# SQL rows to columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a query that produces:

```
ID group  data
-- -----  ----
1  A      123
1  B      456
2  A      234
2  B      567
```

I want to convert that to:

```
ID A data  B data
-- ------  ------
1  123     456
2  234     567
```

Is there an easy way to do this?  The query is already pretty complicated so I'm trying to avoid something like:

```
SELECT data FROM <existing query> WHERE group='A'
OUTER JOIN
SELECT data FROM <existing query> WHERE group='B'
```

Comment: mysql/ sql server or oracle?

Comment: It's a mysql query

Comment: can you also show the query that produces your table?

Comment: @vkp - it's effectively "select id, group, data from <table>", just with a bunch of joins to filter data out, and explode JSON fields

Comment: ok..is the number of groups fixed and is there always one data value per group per id?

Comment: The number of groups is fixed, and there are 0-1 values per group per id

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry - I'm just analyzing some data, dumping it into excel to make charts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when group = 'A' then data end) as group_a,
       max(case when group = 'B' then data end) as group_b
from (<your query here>) q
group by id;
```

You may be able to build this into your existing query, but without seeing it, no suggestions can be made.